# SharePoint Site columns

Tags: content-type, site-column

I have a content type named myContentType with these columns

Title
Person
Age

If i change the name of these columns to this

Title = Hello
Person = Jo
Age = Agee

If i now create a subsite, these columns will have the first name/internal names, title, person and age. How can i fix this? I want to have  the new names.

Answer (score 1):

Once a column is provisioned/created, you cannot change the internal name.

This is one of the areas in SharePoint that requires careful planning.

Comment: Is there any javascript code wich i can change the name of them ?

Comment: Instead of doing/trying any other option , better Create new columns . You will fix with some work around now but it will create huge mess up in future.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: Library -> Library Settings
You can updating the content type by removing then insert the new content type